# Why is PHP function breaking my Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have this scipt call:

```
....
$objResponse->addScriptCall("my_script");
return $objResponse->sendResponse();
```

This works ok but if I try to send a php mail just before, the script is not called:

```
...
$send =& $mailer->Send(); 
$objResponse->addScriptCall("my_script");
return $objResponse->sendResponse();
```

Why is that happening? 
The problem persists even if I replace the email function with a plain:

```
...
print 'hello'; 
$objResponse->addScriptCall("my_script");
return $objResponse->sendResponse();
```

Comment: Is the mail sent successfully? Is there an error message?

Comment: Probably because `$mailer->Send()` encountered a fatal error. Check your logs.

Comment: No, I get a "Could not instantiate mail function" error, but that is because I am in local server. The problem persists if I replace the mail function with just ""print 'Hello'""

Comment: Like ceejayoz said, fatal error.  That would halt execution of the rest of your script.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with JavaScript.

Comment: I agree with Pointy, the error is coming from PHP not JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, it's breaking his function for adding JS to the page, but that has nothing to do with any JS errors.

Comment: Probably you have something like `<script>Some text
function foo(bar){}` and "Some text" gives you syntax error. In you r case Some text = hello

Comment: It could be interpreted as connected to JS if the PHP script is being called from a JS Ajax function. But at this stage it only "appears" to be connected while not actually being so. Purely a PHP problem at this point.

Comment: I didn't say it's a javascript error. Read the title, it says 'PHP breaking javascript'

Comment: Are you using xajax, if so I think it's worth mentioning in your question.

Comment: I don't understand how 'print 'hello'' could cause a fatal error.

Comment: @yann Is this PHP script outputting Javascript as the end result?

Comment: @piddl0r Yes I am using xajax

Comment: Does `->sendResponse()` do any `header()` calls? Most likely your `=&` on the mail call is issuing a warning from assigning an object by reference, causing any later header() calls to fail and issue more warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `error_reporting(0); ini_set('display_errors', 0);` at the top of your script.

The `$mailer->Send()` call is triggering an error, which is being echoed. This is causing a Javascript syntax error which will, as you say, break your Javascript.

This is why calling `print "hello";` also breaks it, because you then have a random, meaningless `hello` at the top of your Javascript.

Comment: You are absolutely right. So if the mail function actually worked in a live site instead of outputing the "could not instantiate mail function" error, then there would be no syntax error in the javascript. Right?

Comment: @yann Correct. You just need to make sure there is absolutely no output appart from your Javascript, or if there is, make sure it is a valid Javascript comment (`/* output */`)